# MongoDB Compass won't display MongoDB Shell

Tags: mongodb, windows, mongodb-compass

I've installed MongoDB 6.0 community edition, with MongoDB Compass. But my Compass doesn't have MongoDB shell that is supposed to be embedded in it.

I'm using Windows 11.

I heard that the shell could be disabled in Settings so i tried to open Settings but it won't open as well.
As I had an old version of Compass when installing Mongo ver6.0, suspecting it could cause the problem so I've also tried uninstall and reinstall everything again.

[Screenshot]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sycHw.png

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Which version of MongoDB Compass are you using? The Mongosh will only appear after opening a connection to a MongoDB Database. Can you post here a screenshot, connected to the Database? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have version 1.39.1. The screenshot is on my question now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [an already reported Compass Issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-7071)

I recommend you:

- log in Jira
- start watching the issue, so you get notifications while it changes

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I had to install the Beta version of Compass for it to work now. But hopefully, this issue will be fixed for main release soon.